# Sharepoint ajax web service compatibality

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, sharepoint, web-config

I have a Sharepoint publishing site that is configured to use ajax 1.0 to use some third party controls (RadEditor, Bamboo).

My problem is I have created a custom web service (.asmx) in a visual studio wspbuilder project and deployed it to the ISAPI folder. The project is set up to use .net 3.5 framework. This works fine for our custom code, but I am having issues making calls to the custom web service via the jQuery $.ajax method. All I get back is generic error messages.

My question is can a website that is configured to use ajax 1.0 make a call to a  .asmx web service that was compiled using the .net 3.5 framework?

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work, I had to add this to the  section of the web.config:

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
```